# Sorting of Reports by Modified Date

Tags: wordpress, civireport, reports, custom-reports

I am working with the Constituent Summary report and then saving a copy with the fields that I want displayed.

One of the fields is Modified Date, but when I go to SORTING, Modified Date is not one of the options.

How can I add Modified Date field to the sorting options of Reports?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to create a new report type in an extension using code that `extends` the existing CRM_Report_Form_Contact_Summary class, and add modified_date into the order_by section. In here https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/539eb78da2cbf9834c5799e3e5e5a6ccbff08ff4/CRM/Report/Form/Contact/Summary.php#L65

Comment: the civix tool makes that pretty straightforward. Alternatively, you could submit a patch if you think adding the sort field the existing report would be generally of value to others.

Comment: I actually ended up using Search Kit to create search I needed and duplicate report, and you can more easily re-arrange the columns and make all columns sortable.